# How to print the file path from an open syscall using ebpf python?

Tags: python, linux, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I use bpf from the python bcc module, and I want that my probe function will print the file path of the current file (kind of a custom simplified opensnoop).
How can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
b = BPF(text="""
#include <linux/ptrace.h>      
#include<linux/sched.h>

BPF_HASH(last);      

int trace_entry(struct pt_regs *ctx)      
{
    char fileName[200] = {0};
    bpf_probe_read(fileName, sizeof(fileName), &PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx));  
    bpf_trace_printk("File Opened<%s>\\n", fileName);      
    return 0;
}
""")

print("Tracing for open... Ctrl-C to end")
b.attach_kprobe(event="do_sys_open", fn_name="trace_entry")
#b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("open"), fn_name='funcky')
b.trace_print()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please read the documentation for bcc and/or try to derive your program from the existing opensnoop, this does not sound like there should be any particular pitfal.

Comment: I have edited what I have done so far. for some reason it does not work as expected- I get "File Opened<>" without the files path.

Comment: My guess is that the `bpf_probe_read()` call fails because you try to read too much data (200 bytes, but file name may not be that long) and this looks unsafe! The opensnoop example from bcc has a way to retrieve the length of the filename, and reads just what's necessary. Alternatively, I think you could try to replace that call by [`bpf_probe_read_user_str()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h?h=v5.5#n2773) instead, so you don't have to care about the actual length of the file name.

Comment: (I forgot to mention that `bpf_probe_read_user_str()` is only available in recent kernels, starting at 5.5. On older kernels, now deprecated `bpf_probe_read_str()` is available. See [rationale](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6ae08ae3dea2cfa03dd3665a3c8475c2d429ef47).)

Answer (score -1):

Easy:
Insert this in kernel code:

```c
// Nicer way to call bpf_trace_printk()
#define bpf_custom_printk(fmt, ...)                     \
        ({                                              \
            char ____fmt[] = fmt;                       \
            bpf_trace_printk(____fmt, sizeof(____fmt),  \
                    ##__VA_ARGS__);                     \
        })
struct pair {
    uint32_t lip; // local IP
    uint32_t rip; // remote IP
};
```

and in kernel code insert print out code. This function call works exactly like `printf` with all format and placeholder ...

```c
bpf_custom_printk("This year is %d\n", 2020);
```

Print output:

```sh
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe
```

Comment: I think I have figured out a way to do it without altering the kernel code. I will make sure it works and update the post.

Comment: @Liroshka what is your final solution?